# Webdriver do not load scroll

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem that is occuring some times.
The page is not showing the scroll, so when I need to find/click an element that is not shown in the screen, I get an exception:

(org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Refreshing the page works, but I would like to know if there is other solutions for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate scroll using `moveToElement` from [Actions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class

```
// Java syntax, but similar to other languages
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elementToMoveTo = driver.findElement(...);
actions.moveToElement(elementToMoveTo).perform();
```